# Good enough Vs well enough

Tags: adverbs

Which one of the two options should I use in the following sentences:

> I can't play football **good/well** enough to be in your team.
>
> The house isn't protected **good/well** enough.
>
> I'm doing **good/well** (talking about making good progress not about health)
>
> I'm doing **good/well** in this game

Comment: All of your sentences have either an adjective or a verb that is modified (_play, protected, doing_ (though you don't find _do_ in that context without an adverb)). These must be modified with an **adverb**, and **well** is the adverb; _good_ is the adjective. Therefore all your sentences should use **_well_**.

Comment: @Kman3 would you be willing to post that as an answer to the question? Seems like one to me.

Comment: @RuslanD Will do.

Comment: do well, play well with or without enough. If  you use good, that is marked as non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentences, either an adjective or a verb is being modified.

> I can't **play** football _________ enough... *(verb)*
>
> This house isn't **protected** _________ enough... *(adjective)*
>
> I'm **doing** _________   /   I'm **doing** _________ in this game ... *(verb)*

These words must be modified using an **adverb**. Out of your two options, there is only one adverb: ***well***.

> I can't play football **well** enough to be *on* your team.
>
> This house isn't protected **well** enough.
>
> I'm doing **well**.
>
> I'm doing **well** in this game.

Quick note: for the last two sentences it appears as if you can take *well* away from the sentence -- you cannot. ***Do well*** is an expression. You cannot say "*I do in this game*", nor can you say "*I'm doing.*" You can, however, say "*I do.*" when you get married.